# Another way to phrase "Earn More Money"?

Tags: word-choice, phrasing

We are creating a page that has a title, "Earn More Money" which states how the swimming coaches can earn a little bit of cash by following certain steps.

However, we find that this phrasing is a bit cheap and boring. Is there another way to phrase it that may or may not be related to swimming & less cheap

As per question: We'd one something casual, not too formal.

Comment: Increase your income/salary/stipend ... I don't know. Do you want "chatty", "slang" or formal and professional-sounding? Do you want a tagline or just another way of saying "earn more money" e.g. "take home more brass"?

Comment: You need to be more specific otherwise this question could be closed for being too broad.

Comment: What are copywriters for?

Answer (score 3):

***Diving into more money*?**

(Note that the word [*dive*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/dive) can be used to mean "to undertake with enthusiasm; to plunge or to go deeply into any subject, question, business, etc.; to explore.")